# How to prepare .txt with double quote, tabs and double quotes to be imported in Excel using Java

Tags: java, excel, csv

I have a Tab-separated text file (basically a CSV) with each value enclosed in double quotes (") and separated by tabs.

Most values are strings and can contain tabs, simple quotes('), double quotes("), and commas, or any character, really.

I would like to import it into Excel using the "Data/From text or CSV" button in Excel, but I got parsing issue in some situation.
In particular, when a value ends with a double quote.
(Ex: ..."value1""tab"value2"...  puts the following text in one cell : value1"value2")

I got a **Java** routine which correctly parses the .txt and chops each line into a List (not a tab because each line can have a different number of values). If relevant, I have access to this code.

My question is: **How can I output a toBePutInExcel.txt file which will be parsed normally, putting each value of my List in different cells, and preserving tabs, simple quotes, double quotes, and commas that can be in these strings?**

I tried to escape internal quotes but cases like "v1\""tab"v2" still confuses Excel.

NB: Theoretically, any character can be in the texts, so I'd rather have an "escaping" strategy rather than taking a weird separator. (My data can be weirder)

NB2: I can't use a "fixed-width" strategy as values vary wildly in size and aligning on the longer would require a lot more space disk.

NB3: I've seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/52157/how-do-i-get-excel-to-import-a-csv-file-with-commas-in-some-of-the-content-field) and similar questions but my data can have commas AND tabs AND anything else. The problem was spaces after the separating commas, but it's not the problem I have.

NB4: I have no constraints about formatting. The source is UTF-8.

**Is there a way to make Excel parse normally such strings?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First result on Google I've found was this (might be useful): https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43190/admin_guide/load/topics/g-escaping-in-csv-formatted-files.html

> The data value with a comma character that is part of the data is enclosed in double quotes. The double quotes that are part of the data are escaped with a double quote even though the field value is enclosed in double quotes.

Lets assume:

- comma (,) is a value separator character
- double quote (") is a escape character

We want to import following values to excel:

- test "a,b"
- test 2
- test "5"
- test 2,3

To achieve this the csv file has to look like this:

```
"test ""a,b""", test 2, test "5","test 2,3"
```

I think you will be able to solve your problem from here.

Comment: I think I missed something fundamental about escaping in CSV.
I knew that two escape characters with text in between escape the text in between.
But I didn't know that **two consecutive escaping characters escape one of them**.
I thought "Special rate ""1.79"" " was equal to "Special rate " + "1.79" + " " and I thought it would give : Special rate 1.79 . But it gives: Special rate "1.79" , which is what I need.

I will test that right away.

Comment: It worked!
This was the missing piece of information I missed:

**Two consecutive escaping characters escape one of them (and not just escaping the empty string between them)**

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar formatting problems after that (since CSV is not rigorously defined as I would think). **Different conventions are used** depending on if the file comes from Excel, MySQL, etc. Some file quote every fields, some others only fields with unsafe characters, etc. All of these mutually incompatible variants are referred to as "CSV", with never-ending compatibility problems.

The [Apache CSV handler](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) understands the different conventions (MySQL in my case), so conversion and parsing are straightforward as they should be.